# What is happening in this line of code?

Tags: java

I came across this while playing with some random code trying to learn Java

```
y = (0x000000FF & ((int)x));
```

**x = -102, 
y = 154**

What is exactly happening in this line?

Comment: Do you know how negative integers are represented in two's complement?

Comment: See [Bitwise operation - AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: @fge If I am not wrong its how negative numbers are represented, eg -2 should be (2^8)-2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That operation gets you the least significant 8 bits of `x` into `y`, thereby masking the 24 higher significant bits.

`-102` in hex representation is `ffffff9a`, which would make `y` to be `9a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-102));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(154));
}
```

prints:

```
11111111111111111111111110011010
10011010
```

Now write it like this instead:

```
11111111111111111111111110011010
00000000000000000000000010011010
```

Finally, 0xff is:

```
00000000000000000000000011111111
```

And you understand your result...